# Check valid phone number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to check if the phone numbers in the table are in the proper format or not. If not I want it to move to another column.

Invalid phone numbers are:

- Less or more than 10 digits (numbers only)
- Number that has alphabet or special characters (except () -)

Sample input:

```
phoneNumber
--------------
+1(111)11-1111
1111111111
11(11)111111
11abcd1111
```

Expected result:

```
phoneNumber
---------------
+1(111)11-1111
1111111111
```

I wrote this query but it doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM Customers
WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '[(][0-9]{3}[)]\s[0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}'
```

Comment: sample data and desired results is very useful for this type of question.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9116/regular-expressions-business-case-examples-with-t-sql/

Comment: You do know that SQL Server doesn't support regex right? Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: That article title is a bit misleading and just uses basic *like* pattern matching - not a regular expression in sight.

Comment: Relevant: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md)

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is never a useful thing to post. Learn to ask [smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to test in your code example does not match your list of requirements, and as noted above, SQL Server LIKE does not support the generalized type of regular expression that you have coded. Specifically, `{3}` and `\s` are not supported.

Using just your stated requirements, you can first check that the string does not contain any invalid characters and then separately check that the string contains exactly 10 digits after removing the valid non-numeric characters.

Something like:

```
SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM Customers
WHERE PhoneNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9()-]%'
AND REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneNumber, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '')) LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
-- AND LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PhoneNumber, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '')) = 10 -- Alternate test
```

Note that this will still allow some unusual cases like ')123(45678-9-0-`.

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a26ba5a211cf65966cb7a7f6b628eb01).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But some of the valid numbers are still in phonenumber column in the example you attached. 
E.x
(565)616-2651 ||
7133985242

Comment: @Rnue -  Both of those numbers are valid according to the rules you defined. Why shouldn't they be part of the expected results?  It may be time to revisit your requirements to make sure they are fully defined.